# Responsive bootstrap menu issues

Tags: html, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my app has a primary menu and then once a user is logged in, a secondary menu. Works fine and looks fine with full size (first image shown). When my app hits its media queries as shown in code below, thats why things are getting messed up and despite my best efforts, I am having issues. Let me show images and then tell more of what is happening after.

So at full screen with user logged in, both menus show as:

[image]

But then when go to a tablet size of 768px in width, this is where the issues start. You can see that the drop down arrow not right for top menu, and secondary menu, no arrow at all. You can also see that the text that shows for the top menu has a bad z-index despite my updates and changes.

[image]

[image]

So my menu (outside of the angular injection for what shows) is mainly in the index.html for the top menu, then the secondary (as shown in the code) gets brought in via a partial.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController" style="border-bottom: #ab2328 3px solid;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" ng-click="navbarExpanded = !navbarExpanded">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            </button>
            <a ng-show="!isSWA" class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.naviabenefits.com" target="_blank"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia.png"></a>
            <a ng-show="isSWA" class="navbar-brand" href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/" target="_blank"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!navbarExpanded">
            <!-- pebb main nav -->
            <ul ng-show="isSWA" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                <li ng-show="authentication.isAdmin"><a href="#/admin/ppt">admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/" target="_blank">benefits we offer</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/enrollment/" target="_blank">enrollment</a></li>`
                <li><a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/forms-documents/" target="_blank">forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/faq/" target="_blank">faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://apps.sig-is.org/SIGISPublicRpts/IIASMerchantList.aspx" target="_blank">IIAS merchant list</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/about/" target="_blank">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://pebb.naviabenefits.com/contact/" target="_blank">contact us</a></li>
                <li ng-show="authentication.isAuth"><a id="signOut" href="#/logout">log out <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul ng-show="!isSWA" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-show="authentication.isAdmin"><a href="#/admin/ppt">admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/products-and-services/" target="_blank">products + services</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/about/" target="_blank">about us</a></li>`
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/testimonials/" target="_blank">testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/careers/" target="_blank">careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/news/" target="_blank">news</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/blog/" target="_blank">blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/contact/" target="_blank">contact us</a></li>
                <li ng-show="authentication.isAuth"><a id="signOut" href="#/logout">log out <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbarSecondary navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController" ng-show="authentication.isAuth">
    <div class="container">
        <div  ng-include="'ppt/views/menu.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-view="">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the div with the ng-include, I am calling the partial and that code is:

```
<div class="navbarSecondary collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!navbarExpanded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
            <a href="#/pptHome">
                Participants Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- secondary menu for SWA -->
        <li class="dropdown" ng-show="isSWA">
            <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/" target="_blank" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Benefits We Offer
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/health-care-fsa/"  target="_blank" >
                        Medical Flexible Spending Arrangement
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/dependent-care-assistance-program/" target="_blank" >
                        Dependent Care Assistance Program
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/fsa-vs-hsa/" target="_blank" >
                        FSA vs. HSA Comparison
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" ng-show="!isSWA">
            <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/" target="_blank" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Benefits & Info
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/health-care-fsa/"  target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('HealthCare')">
                        Health Care FSA
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/day-care-fsa/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('DayCare')">
                        Day Care FSA
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/limited-health-care/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('Limited')">
                        Limited Health Care FSA
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/hsa/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('HSA')">
                        Health Savings Account (HSA)
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/gonavia-commuter-benefits/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('GoNavia')">
                        GoNavia Commuter Benefits
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/health-reimbursement-arrangement/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('HRA')">
                        Health Reimbursement Arrangement (HRA)
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/dental-reimbursement-plan/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('DirectReimb')">
                        Direct Reimbursement Plan
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/benefits/cobra/" target="_blank" ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('COBRA')">
                        COBRA
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- secondary menu for SWA -->
        <li class="dropdown" ng-show="isSWA">
            <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/tools/" target="_blank" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Tools & Resources
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/benefits/expenses/" target="_blank">
                        Expenses
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/tools/navia-benefits-card/" target="_blank">
                        Navia Debit Card
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/tools/mynavia-mobile-app/" target="_blank">
                        MyNavia Mobile App
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/tools/tax-savings-calculator/" target="_blank">
                        Tax Savings Calculator
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" ng-show="!isSWA">
            <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/" target="_blank" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Tools & Resources
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/expenses/" target="_blank">
                        Expenses
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('BenefitCard')">
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/benefits-card/" target="_blank">
                      Navia Benefits Debit Card
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('MobileApp')">
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/mynavia-app/" target="_blank">
                        MyNavia Mobile App
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('FlexConnect')">
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/flex-connect/" target="_blank">
                        FlexConnect
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('OnlineClaim')">
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/online-claim-submission/" target="_blank">
                        Online Claim Submission
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="hasMenuBenefit('OnlineSubst')">
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/online-debit-card-substantiation/" target="_blank">
                        Online Debit Card Substantiation
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/tax-savings-calculator/" target="_blank">
                        Tax Savings Calculator
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/tutorial-videos/" target="_blank">
                        Tutorial Videos
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/faq/" target="_blank">
                        FAQ
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/participants/resources/forms-documents/" target="_blank">
                        Forms & Documents
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And finally, with my over rides to bootstrap for color, font, etc..., my CSS is as (took out the media breakpoints as none were working as expected):

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbarSecondary {
    background-color: #ab2328;
    height: 66px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.navbarSecondary > li.dropdown.open > ul {
    background-color: #2dccd3;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar.navbarSecondary.navbar-inverse.ng-scope > div > div > div > ul > li > a:hover, .navbar.navbarSecondary.navbar-inverse.ng-scope > div > div > div > ul > li > a:active, .navbar.navbarSecondary.navbar-inverse.ng-scope > div > div > div > ul > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #68070b;
}

.navbarSecondary.navbar-inverse.ng-scope > div > div > div > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 25px 20px 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#signOut {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background-color: #ab2328;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#signOut:hover, #signOut:active {
    background-color: #68070b;
}

.sub-menu {
    background-color: #2dccd3;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.sub-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15.6px;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px 40px;
}

.sub-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #24a4a9;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li >a {
    color: #2d3130;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
    color: #ab2328;
}
```

I have tried asnd tried using chrome dev tools and setting media breakpoints to no avail to get this work. Am hoping some of you can chime and in give some help. Is much appreciated.

Comment: Put it in a code snippet or a jsfiddle

Comment: With the code as such, the fiddle is tough. Can someone not see what I am doing from what I provided?

Comment: Not really. I'd have to copy it into a fiddle to even hope to find the issue.

Comment: Though, I do understand what you mean, since you have angular in there

Comment: Best I have is this, but it still doesn't show the full picture: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ Basically, I am trying to use bootstrap for all except where I show the style overrides. Oops...that didnt fork right.

Comment: Here is a different fiddle, but still, not representative of what I can have locally: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19848/